# python Defaultdict TypeError: extend() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Tags: python

I get the error "extend() takes exactly one argument (0 given)" but I am passing a list the the extend method.

I also stepped through the code in a debug mode and 'parts' is definitely of type list with length one at the time of being passed to .extend().

```
def split_rows(df, delim = "|"):
    cols = list(df.columns)
    newdf = defaultdict.fromkeys(cols, list)

    for index, row in df.head().iterrows():
        for col in cols:
            cell = str(row[col])
            parts = cell.split(delim)
            print(parts)
            print(type(parts))
            newdf[col].extend(parts)

    for col in cols:
        print(col, len(newdf[col]))

split_rows(artist_df)
```

output:

```py
['1979.486.1']
<class 'list'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\mschm\Desktop\Masters_DU\Comp_4447\Final_Project\COMP4447_Project\data_cleaning.ipynb Cell 19' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 split_rows(artist_df)

c:\Users\mschm\Desktop\Masters_DU\Comp_4447\Final_Project\COMP4447_Project\data_cleaning.ipynb Cell 18' in split_rows(df, delim)
      9         print(parts)
     10         print(type(parts))
---> 11         newdf[col].extend(parts)
     15 for col in cols:
     16     print(col, len(newdf[col]))

TypeError: extend() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Comment: Could you also add "debugging" statements for `newdf[col]`?

Answer (score 0):

The Error is :

```
from collections import defaultdict
newdf = defaultdict.fromkeys(["a","b"], list) # This line is error
newdf["a"].extend([1,2]) # This will create same error as list.extend() takes exactly one argument (0 given) because list is not initialized yet.


newdf = defaultdict.fromkeys(["a","b"], list()) # This line is correct
```

Explaination

```
a = defaultdict(list) # When initializing defaultdict you need callable function so list will work here but

a = defaultdict.fromkeys([a,b,c], list()) # When created using fromkeys it expects second argument to be some value not any callable function so list() will work because value is __[]__.
```

---

If we will use above method then after doing extend it will create an issue like this:
a["a"].extend([1,2,3]) # This will result in {"a": [1,2,3], "b":[1,2,3], "c":[1,2,3]}
To avoid this thing and also to handle your case you can try below method to create default dictionary from given keys:

```
de_l=defaultdict(list,{k:[] for k in ['a', 'b', 'c']}) # This will create default dictionary with list as an callable and also include your keys.
```

OR simply you can create defaultdict with list callable and then extend any of the key.

```
de_l = defaultdict(list)
```

Your program should work fine with this code as well

```
def split_rows(df, delim = "|"):
    cols = list(df.columns)
    newdf = defaultdict(list)  # We don't need to call fromkeys

    for index, row in df.head().iterrows():
        for col in cols:
            cell = str(row[col])
            parts = cell.split(delim)
            print(parts)
            print(type(parts))
            newdf[col].extend(parts)

    for col in cols:
        print(col, len(newdf[col]))

split_rows(artist_df)
```

Comment: Ah thank you, that indeed does work. Can you provide some reasoning for that? 

The documentation clearly shows with no parenthesis: `d = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Without parenthesis it will work if you are not creating it fromkeys method like defaultdict(list) this will work , but when you are using fromkeys method then second parameter expects default value which should not be some classname as you have passed. So replacing list with list() will work for you. In short defaultdict initialization expects __callable__ while fromkeys value expects __value__  so __list__ is callable while __list()__ is value.

Comment: The trouble with the `fromkeys()` class method is that the second parameter will be used as the default value for all keys created. This means that a subsequent call to `extend()` will give all entries the same value. I'm sure that is not what the OP requires

Comment: @quamrana Correct in that case OP should not use defaultdict.fromkeys() method.